# Types of optimisations happen in cpp relaxed memory model?

Tags: c++, optimization, memory-model

Finding it really hard to find all sorts of optimisations that takes place in relaxed memory model.

I have came across: **speculation** and **register allocation**, but sure the list don't ends here.

What are the various sort of compiler optimisations that happen when developer try to use relaxed memory model in cpp?

Answer (score 0):

Speculation is a general term, there are dozens of types. Register allocation is part of the natural process of compilation (for logical registers) and CPU work (for physical registers, is such exist) - neither of these things is related to relaxed memory models.

The main optimization I could think of is that relaxed memory models allow store reordering, with common compilers and CPUs otherwise prevent. This allows better memory parallelism since you don't serialize your writes, and even better cache hit rates since you can use cached lines without stalling and risking losing the line from cache. This also allows better chances of combining multiple stores to the same cacheline (write combining), which gives better bandwidth.

I'm mostly talking about stores because loads are usually already being optimized by the hardware in modern out-of-order CPUs. There are some precautions used to detect problems there, but the penalty is probably not too bad. 
There are also barriers, and some weak models can use lighter ones than the heavy fences x86 is doing, but you may actually have to use more fences on a weaker model so it really depends on what you're trying to achieve and how.